# Reading order of Ant-Man comics

Tags: marvel, suggested-order, ant-man

I would like to read comic books about Ant-Man, but I don't quite know where to start.

I know his debut was in Tales To Astonish #27. Should I start there? If I do, do I have to  read the previous issues of Tales To astonish to understand whats going on?

I also know that he eventually joins the Avengers. Can I jump around in the Avengers and just read issues that involve him, or do I just need to read all of The Avengers to get a good understand of whats going on?

Eventually he gets his on series. Will I understand whats going on there if I just jump in and start reading that, or does it reference the older comics too much.

**Where should I start to fully understand Ant-Man?**

Comment: The Marvel wikia has a [recommended reading order for Ant-Man](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Ant-Man_Recommended_Reading), which may be a good place to start.

Answer (score -3):

Google Hank Pym. While an original Avenger, Hank has gone through many ID's (i.e. Giant-Man, Goliath, Yellowjacket, Dr. Pym, etc. ) He's arguably the most flawed member of the Avengers. Try scans of Avengers 1-8, and his rebirth in West Coast Avengers.

Comment: Telling people to Google things is very poor site etiquette. You seem to be back to posting lots of low-value answers and treating the site like a forum.

Comment: Nope, sorry about that. I'm working as a Hotel Night Manager right now and sometimes I start a post but get caught up with late check-ins, early arrivals, etc. In short, I get halfway through my posting and have to get back to the desk

Comment: I do realize my posts aren't always in the proper form but I usually type out an outline and then source out my references. Sometimes though I'm screwed for time...

Comment: Why not have a read through some of the higher-voted posts to get a feel for the site's style? It's fast better to post a single solid answer than a dozen half-assed ones, especially when you're just starting out.